# Shell script not reading a single line in between random

Tags: excel, shell, csv

I am using shell script to read a CSV file. My script is below. I am facing a weird issue where i am inputing a file with 2000 entries and just outputing everything to a new csv file. Randomly i see one less entry in the newly created csv file. I am not sure why one entry is missing in the new csv file. Its not the first or last entry but a random middle entry. So just puzled on whats happening?

**script**:

```
#!/bin/bash


while read input1 input2
do

id=$input1
value=$input2
echo "$id , $value" >> output.xslx

done < input_file.csv
```

Any suggestions are apreciated.

Comment: You say the input is CSV, i.e. fields separated by comma. But your `read` command splits on spaces, not comma.

Comment: I have give the IFS with ',' which somehow removes the new lines. But still the major issue of missing a record is a big worry. Not sure why am i missing a record :( Any thoughts on that please? @user1934428

Comment: By comparing the input to the output, you can easily find out, which line(s) are missing. If you post such an example of missing lines, together with the line before and the line after, this should give some insight.

Comment: You should also update your post so that we can see the way you set IFS.

Comment: Are you sure that you don't have entries in your CSV which span several lines, or fields containing a comma?

Answer (score 1):

Use `read` with the option `-r` to ignore backslashes:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read -r input1 input2;do
   id=$input1
   value=$input2
   echo "$id , $value" >> output.xslx
done < input_file.csv
```